# How to add vertical line to RemoteView for custom Android Notifications?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-notifications, remoteview

I'm struggling to add a vertical line to a custom Android Notification. I've tried adding a view like this to my Relative Layout:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/line_vertical"
    android:layout_width="1dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_logo"
    android:background="#0000FF" />
```

But when I fire the notification, I get the following Exception:
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package XXX: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(package=XXX)

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't inflate just any view in a `RemoteView`. Change your `View` to an empty `TextView` or `ImageView`.

> A RemoteViews object (and, consequently, an App Widget) can support the following layout classes:
>
> ```
> FrameLayout
> LinearLayout
> RelativeLayout
> ```
>
> And the following widget classes:
>
> ```
> AnalogClock
> Button
> Chronometer
> ImageButton
> ImageView
> ProgressBar
> TextView
> ViewFlipper
> ListView
> GridView
> StackView
> AdapterViewFlipper
> ```
>
> Descendants of these classes are not supported.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout

Comment: You da man K-ballo. Using an ImageView worked perfectly. Here's my code:
`<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />`

Comment: Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:alpha="0.3"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />
```

We have to add like this.