# How to fix: android.app.RemoteServiceException without any message (not related to Bad Notification or Broadcast)

Tags: android, crash, android-7.0-nougat, remoteserviceexception

I have an android.app.RemoteServiceException (RSE) but without any message.
I get the following crash report on Google Play Console. When I get a RSE due to a bad Notification or Broadcast I get the related message but in this case it is a black crash.

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1813)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6781)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

I started getting these crashes primarily on Android 7 and Samsung devices (in large).

[image: Android versions and devices]

We are following standard guidelines for Notifications and Broadcasts.

```
targetSdkVersion 25
compileSdkVersion 26
```

I have gone through many StackOverflow questions related to RemoteServiceException but not been able to find RCA hence posting the new question.
Listed below are the questions I have checked and not been able to find a resolution for RSE:

- [How to fix: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package *: Couldn't create icon: StatusBarIcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317659/how-to-fix-android-app-remoteserviceexception-bad-notification-posted-from-pac)
- [How to add vertical line to RemoteView for custom Android Notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607097/how-to-add-vertical-line-to-remoteview-for-custom-android-notifications)
- [How to fix this bug : "android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24968556/how-to-fix-this-bug-android-app-remoteserviceexception-bad-notification-post)
- [FCM - How to fix android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124458/fcm-how-to-fix-android-app-remoteserviceexception-bad-notification-posted-fro)
- [Android - getting "can't deliver broadcast" error on dynamically registered broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40175713/android-getting-cant-deliver-broadcast-error-on-dynamically-registered-broa)
- [Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: can't deliver broadcast at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46971153/fatal-exception-android-app-remoteserviceexception-cant-deliver-broadcast-at)

Comment: I have the same issue as well. It'd be great if anyone posted what the solution is.

Comment: Any news on this? I have got exactly the same stack trace in Google Play Console. Have not been able to reproduce this myself.

Answer (score 2):

if you have started service using startforgroundservice()

then you have to call startforground() in service oncreate by following the google instructions for oreo.

Answer (score 0):

It might be very late, but do you have content providers in your app?
If they are, are they properly declared in the manifest?
I saw ActivityThread class code for API 26. The line where the error happens is 1813.

```
 case INSTALL_PROVIDER:
                handleInstallProvider((ProviderInfo) msg.obj);
                break;
```

Following the code shows that the app is not able to publish the content provider and crashing there.

```
 try {
        ActivityManager.getService().publishContentProviders(
            getApplicationThread(), results);
    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
        throw ex.rethrowFromSystemServer();
    }
```

Late!! but might help others to debug their case.